# How to search exact string using MySql Query which avoids extended values?

Tags: mysql, sql

My Query looks like

```
$search_query = db_query("SELECT nd.nid, users.name, nd.type FROM node as nd 
LEFT JOIN node_revisions as nd_rev ON nd_rev.nid = nd.nid AND nd_rev.vid = nd.vid 
LEFT JOIN users ON nd.uid = users.uid 
WHERE nd.status = 1 AND nd_rev.body LIKE LOWER('%node/100%') 
AND nd.nid NOT IN(SELECT DISTINCT nid FROM term_node WHERE tid = 293)");
```

This query actually returns all the matches from node_revisions.body field, Which includes
node/1000, node/1001.... Etc.,

I want to get only the result of exact match where possible like

```
"node/100"
"node/100/"
"/node/100"
"/node/100/"
'node/100'
'node/100/'
'/node/100'
'/node/100/'
```

and not like

```
"node/1006"
"node/10064/"
"/node/1000"
"/node/10001/"
'node/10023'
'node/1005/'
'/node/1001'
'/node/10069/'
```

This above query returned me result which has string like below..
   ..a href="/node/1006"

How to avoid this kind of errors? Please help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh ya... I got an resolution for this.. I redefined my query like below and it gives me result as expected..

```
$search_query = db_query("SELECT nd.nid, users.name, nd.type FROM node as nd 
LEFT JOIN node_revisions as nd_rev ON nd_rev.nid = nd.nid AND nd_rev.vid = nd.vid 
LEFT JOIN users ON nd.uid = users.uid 
WHERE nd.status = 1 AND nd_rev.body RLIKE '[[:<:]]" . $search_string . "[[:>:]]' 
AND nd.nid NOT IN(SELECT DISTINCT nid FROM term_node WHERE tid = 293)");
```

Look at

```
nd_rev.body RLIKE '[[:<:]]" . $search_string . "[[:>:]]'
```

This is what i expected

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the  `%` after 100 so the search won't consider any digit after 100, like this:

```
LOWER('%node/100')
```

Answer (score 0):

Then consider the following `Regular Expression`

**Example:**

```
`nd_rev.body` REGEXP "^/?node/100/?$"
```

Comment: One of my node which has id 1666 has string some thing like "..information, see <a href="/node/1006">..." .  My query whick used your above mentioned regular expression is not returning the above match.. QUERY : SELECT nd.nid, users.name, nd.type FROM node as nd LEFT JOIN node_revisions as nd_rev ON nd_rev.nid = nd.nid AND nd_rev.vid = nd.vid LEFT JOIN users ON nd.uid = users.uid 
WHERE nd.status = 1 AND nd_rev.body REGEXP "^/?node/1006/?$"